# Complement of conditional probability (trivial probability question)

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

This is a trivial question but I just wanted to check whether:

If $P(A|B) = 0.90$ then $P(A^C|B) = 0.10$

Comment: Yes this is indeed the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, we have the complement rule for conditional probability.

The prove proceeds as follow:

$$P(A^c|B)=\frac{P(A^c\cap B)}{P(B)}=\frac{P(B)-P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}=1-\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}=1-P(A|B).$$